# Understanding Cause of NullPointerException in Java NIO Socket Channel

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I've put together a simple echo type server app using java nio. While it is able to write the data, it always throws the following exception. Can anyone explain why this is happening? My code is below. Before the thread containing the run method is created I ensure the `key.isAcceptable()` is true.

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedPool(5);
...
try {
    pool.execute(                                           
        new Thread() {
            @Override public void run() {
                ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                SocketChannel sc = null;
                try {
                    sc = ssc.accept();
                    String response = "Server thread (" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ") Current time: " + new Date();
                    ByteBuffer bytes = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(response));
                    sc.write(bytes);
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());                                                                              
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (sc.isOpen()) sc.close(); // This is the line causing the exception to be thrown. If the check is changed to (sc != null) no exceptions are thrown.
                    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
} catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Interrupted!");
}
```

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2"
>   60java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
>     at EchoServer$1.run(EchoServer.java:61)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
> ```
>
> utor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: @EJP: The stack trace has been added. NOTE: Writing to the socket channel does NOT cause an exception and the client receives ALL the transmitted data. If the if statement is changed to `if (sc != null) sc.close();` no exceptions are thrown. I don't understand why the channel is not null when I write to it, but when I try to close it, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the SocketChannel returned by ssc.accept is null, which in turn implies that the ServerSocketChannel is in non-blocking mode and there is no pending connection.

Comment: @lainM: I'ved double checked and `ssc.accept()` does return a `SocketChannel` object; the issue seemingly is with the `ExecutorService` pool, specifically where the code tries to close the socket channel -- `sc.close()`

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for `ServerSocketChannel` says:

```
If this channel is in non-blocking mode then this method will immediately 
return null if there are no pending connections. Otherwise it will block 
indefinitely until a new connection is available or an I/O error occurs.
```

Are you sure `ssc.accept()` isn't returning `null` for just that reason?

Comment: I'm sure `ssc.accept()` isn't returning `null`. However, based on your quote above I believe the root cause is the `ExecutorService` pool (see OP).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @IainM and @QuantumMechanic, you aren't checking 'sc' for null. If the NPE arises in sc.close(), 'sc' was null, I would say you got an NPE calling sc.write(), and another one in the finally{} block calling sc.close().

You also aren't checking the result of the write(), so you may be writing partial messages or indeed nothing at all. You also have a completely pointless test for sc.isOpen(). It is either null or open in this code, there is no other possibility.

And I don't know how you can call this thing an echo server when it doesn't read any input.

This is not the way to use NIO. The whole idea is that you don't need extra threads. There is something seriously wrong with your entire design.

You are also lying to yourself by printing "Interrupted!" on *any* exception, and concealing the actual exception by not printing its message or stack trace. This is not the way to use exceptions either.

Comment: 'sc' is ONLY null when attempting to close it. You're right I wasn't actively checking the results of write(); I was simple looking at the output of the client, which displayed ALL the content the server was supposed to send. As for this being an 'echo server', it originally did have both read and write, but once I encountered the NPE error, I whittled it done to only the 'w rite' components.

Comment: As I understand it, NIO is an alternative to the paradigm of 1 connection and 1 thread. In my toy app, it's many connections to a few threads; therefore it is still within the scope of NIO. If you disagree, please elaborate on why. Lastly, printing "Interrupted!" is obviously not a best practice; there were no issues with that part of the code so I saw no point in adding a `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: @dansten None of that alters the fact that you should check the write() result and react accordingly, or that you should print the actual exception rather than assuming it was an interruption. Or that you don't need a separate thread to process non-blocking I/O. In this case possibly OP_ACCEPT is being triggered twice due your thread design, so the second thread gets a null from accept() while the first one accepts and writes. I would move at least the accept processing back into the select loop, maybe the write() processing as well.